# flutterBlue.connect(device, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),).listen(null); in flutter

Tags: flutter

sorry,I am a beginner and my English is very bad
i have a trouble in Flutter.
i reference https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue 
I want to use flutter to communicate with the ear thermometer device.
when i reopen bluetooth and it can work,but I reopen app and excute second it show error.
i guess bluetooth gatt cahce is causing a error.
how can i solve it?

my code

```
deviceConnection = flutterBlue.scan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),).listen((scanResult) async {
    device = scanResult.device;
    deviceConnection2 = await flutterBlue.connect(device, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),).listen(null);//this line error is error 1
    deviceStateSubscription = device.onStateChanged().listen((s) async {
        await device.discoverServices().then((s) async {//this is error 2
            .........
        }
    }
}
```

it show these error

error 1

> Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>       PlatformException(already_connected, connection with device already exists, null)

error 2

> Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>       PlatformException(get_services_error, no instance of BluetoothGatt, have you connected first?, null)

Answer (score 0):

Error 1

```
Dart Error: Unhandled exception: PlatformException(already_connected, connection with device already exists, null)
```

Since the app detected that a bluetooth device is already connected, one workaround is check for any connected device disconnect it. You can create a function that does this like the one in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/391#issuecomment-541752842):

> What you can do here is that you check for any connected devices and
> then disconnect them. I have written a function that does just that,
> here it is:
>
> ```
> checkConnectedDevices() async{
>
>     connectedDevices = await flutterBlue.connectedDevices.whenComplete((){
>       print(connectedDevices);
>       for(int i = 0; i < connectedDevices.length; i++){
>         connectedDevices[i].disconnect();
>       }
>     });
>
>   }
> ```

---

Error 2

```
Dart Error: Unhandled exception: PlatformException(get_services_error, no instance of BluetoothGatt, have you connected first?, null)
```

Since there is an error connecting to the device, you will not be able to call the `discoverServices()`. Because you need to be connected to a device before you can call this function. Check the following GitHub discussions related to this error:

- [connected ' discoverServices ' is't get #426](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/426)
- [discoverServices is broken #535](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/535)